# Using async(), but performance time is worse

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, concurrency

I watched async() usage from The Cherno Youtube channel, and I tried to do in my code. However the result time with async() turned out to be significantly slower than normal method.

I tried to implement an addition function to push back independent values into a vector, and because values are independent, I used async() function to try to do it with multithreading and use  library to implement a class called Time to record performance. However, the result with async() turned out to be slower that normal push back as the size increases.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>


//A class Time to record the function running time
class Time{
...
};



//Implement async()
static std::mutex the_lock;

static void addition(std::vector<int>* array, int index){
    int num = index + 2;
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock (the_lock);
    array->push_back(num);
}


//Main function
#define timer() Time timer##__LINE__
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> array;
    int test_size = 100;
    std::vector<std::future<void>> f;


    
    /* Compare the asynchrouns push back method and normal push back method by recording their running time */
    {
        timer();
        for(int i = 0; i < test_size; ++i){
            f.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, addition, &array, i));
        }
    }


    {
        timer();
        for(int i = 0; i < test_size; ++i){
            array.push_back(i + 2);
        }
    }
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

The result of Size 100

```
Asychrouns Function is running...
1436 μs

Normal push back function is running...
27 μs
```

Size 1000

```
Asychrouns Function is running...
8351 μs

Normal push back function is running...
25 μs
```

Size 10000 is even worse.

Could anybody help me check what is wrong?

Comment: Creating a thread and waiting for it to be scheduled is far more expensive than a push_back

Comment: Best way for performance is to `reserve()` all the vectors you use across threads. Then you don't need guards to protect against re-allocing vectors which uses a lot of overhead.